# Shortcut for adding id="" and class="" to HTML tags in Sublime Text 2

Tags: html, css, sublimetext2, shortcut

How do you set up Sublime Text 2 so that typing a **`.` (period) produces `class=" "`** and **`#` (hash) produces `id=" "`** when typing an opening HTML tag?

Comment: What exactly did you try to solve the problem? What and where did you search?

Comment: For close voters: Sublime Text is an editor, very frequently used for coding. Coding tools are on-topic on [SO].

Comment: I found the answer. I'm not too familiar with this site so I just answered it below.

Comment: Posting the solution as an answer is correct, you should also mark it as accepted once the system lets you to. Editing the *answer* into the *question* is not appropriate though, I reverted your edit.

Answer (score 10):

Type foo.bar, press Tab, and you'll get

```
<foo class="bar"></foo>
```

There's also foo#bar (for id instead of class). Both are implemented in Packages/HTML/html_completions.py

Comment: simple and easy to use. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer. Go to: Preferences -> Setting -> User.

add the following text between the curly braces, then save the file:

```
"auto_id_class": true,
```

this allows you to add `id=" "` and `class=" "` into HTML tags quickly, just by typing a `#` or `.`

If you use sublime text it's a nice feature.

Answer (score 5):

Check out http://emmet.io/, its a plugin for sublime that helps with html and css.

For example:

```
.class
```

becomes

```
<div class="class"></div>
```

More examples can be found [here](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/),

Answer (score 0):

I am using ST3 but `"auto_id_class": true,` (**@Paul_S answer**) did not work for me. Instead I created a custom snippet quickly. Check out snippet below. Note:    the scope `<scope>meta.tag.other.html, meta.tag.block.any.html, meta.tag.inline.any.html</scope>` could be better/further refined but since it worked for me so didn't bother researching further.

**ID**

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
id="${1}"
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>#</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>meta.tag.other.html, meta.tag.block.any.html, meta.tag.inline.any.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

**Class**

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
class="${1}"
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>.</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>meta.tag.other.html, meta.tag.block.any.html, meta.tag.inline.any.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In ST3 you can use the following:

foo.class[tab]

foo#id[tab]

**For example:**

div.row[tab]

**Result:**

```
<div class="row">|</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).